# Free SSH server to test upload of files over SSH

Tags: webapp-rec

I am looking for a free web-based SSH server which I can do a quick test of file upload over SSH.

Comment: Do you mean SSL (i.e. https?)

Comment: Secure FTP over SSH connection. I got a freeSSHd, http://www.freesshd.com/?ctt=download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a free shell account at [Shellmix](http://shellmix.com/index.php/free-account/free-shell-account). It has free 200 MB of hard disk space. Should be adequate for your needs.