# Web based SSH Client

Tags: webapp-rec

I am looking for a SSH Client that I can open with my browser.
Basically I am want to avoid the need to download any special software to do it, I am in a Windows machine and I am don't want to download Putty or any of kind of software in order to connect to my home machine.

In addition to that my company blocked the port for SSH so I am can't do it anyway.

I have did a search on this site but couldn't find anything about it.
After I did a Google search for it, I can come up with one or two, but I would like to use one that I can trust that isn't capture my passwards or same my ssh server IP address.

So I want to hear from you , if you have any Web based SSH Client that you know about.

Comment: See [this question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16041/free-ssh-server-to-test-upload-of-files-over-ssh).

Comment: I don't think a free shell account is going to help in this case (at least given the information here).

Comment: @Alex: i am need Cliet not a Server.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control of the box you are connecting to, you can install [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/), which, amongst other things, it provides a Java based SSH client.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Tiny-Shell](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinysh/) will help.

Answer (score 0):

Java SSH clients won't help if your SSH port is blocked. In that case you'd probably want to use something like [Shell In A Box](http://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/), which is a web-based terminal connected to an SSH client. You run it on your home machine and connect to it via HTTPS (so at least in theory no one can get your passwords). This way all you need open on your end is port 443. You may want to use Apache's proxy module, depending on your configuration.

I find that this generally works well, although it's not quite as fast as I'd like when updating the whole screen (at least over a 768kbps connection).